# Adding Solana to Edinburgh Decentralization Index

Tags: python, jsonrpc-api, decentralization

I'm an independent crypto guy working on trying to improve and expand the Edinburgh Decentralization Index (EDI) that recently relased its alpha version:

[http://blockchainlab.inf.ed.ac.uk/edi-dashboard](http://blockchainlab.inf.ed.ac.uk/edi-dashboard/)

I am not affiliated with the researchers or grant funders in any way, I'm simply in pursuit of accurate data.  I've already made some small corrections to Cardano's pool groupings reflect more accurate numbers as detailed in this X thread:

https://x.com/Cerkoryn/status/1764073054353711529

I don't personally participate in the Solana community/ecosystem but I would nonetheless like to go about adding accurate consensus data for Solana.  Unfortunately, I don't seem to understand Solana quite enough at the moment to pull what I need from the JSON RPC available at https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com.

What I'm looking for is a list of blocks(shreds?) with block number, timestamp, reward_address(es) for the entity that created the block, and any sort of identifiers that can be associated with the block creator.  Here are some examples of the data for Ethereum and Cardano:

Ethereum.json

```
{"number": 4832686, "timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:02+00:00", "reward_addresses": "0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8", "identifiers": "0x65746865726d696e652d657533"}
{"number": 4832687, "timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:12+00:00", "reward_addresses": "0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5", "identifiers": "0x6e616e6f706f6f6c2e6f7267"}
{"number": 4832688, "timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:14+00:00", "reward_addresses": "0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8", "identifiers": "0x65746865726d696e652d65753131"}
{"number": 4832689, "timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:19+00:00", "reward_addresses": "0x829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830", "identifiers": "0xe4b883e5bda9e7a59ee4bb99e9b1bc"}
{"number": 4832690, "timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:25+00:00", "reward_addresses": "0x6b7d50bb8fab584e54251a10e1c6cfa51dd7b618", "identifiers": "0x70616e64615f706f6f6c"}
{"number": 4832691, "timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:34+00:00", "reward_addresses": "0xb2930b35844a230f00e51431acae96fe543a0347", "identifiers": "0x7438"}
{"number": 4832692, "timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:51+00:00", "reward_addresses": "0x52bc44d5378309ee2abf1539bf71de1b7d7be3b5", "identifiers": "0x6e616e6f706f6f6c2e6f7267"}
...
```

Cardano.json

```
{"number": 96062504, "identifiers": "TLK", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:46:35", "reward_addresses": "fe59e220d8036bd7533bf393e26abde56ec7d49fa632e57bf696d134"}
{"number": 96062511, "identifiers": "GCD", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:46:42", "reward_addresses": "3a203ec1a8bae5098be953c3759e9fae42eea3d5714293500c6b3013"}
{"number": 96062516, "identifiers": "ZZZ", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:46:47", "reward_addresses": "6184f6e7229530a2d1f9f746112406100e2696dd7439ff8c52750700"}
{"number": 96062536, "identifiers": "SPS3", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:47:07", "reward_addresses": "f839821b8c95969d853e4b547952b84a3bb20cd96c6b564ddfd95c0b"}
{"number": 96062642, "identifiers": "N/A", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:48:53", "reward_addresses": "27ca1ffda65d1ef326c9e6a717210c98b10a0e17910c0ab6d9eeb6fb"}
{"number": 96062673, "identifiers": "IOG1", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:49:24", "reward_addresses": "d9812f8d30b5db4b03e5b76cfd242db9cd2763da4671ed062be808a0"}
{"number": 96062686, "identifiers": "WAV1", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:49:37", "reward_addresses": "e985b5698de1386439e62b5b7ab2cc9f814b91b4a1fef5970f38694d"}
{"number": 96062686, "identifiers": "WAV1", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:49:37", "reward_addresses": "e985b5698de1386439e62b5b7ab2cc9f814b91b4a1fef5970f38694d"}
{"number": 96062719, "identifiers": "ZZZ2", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:50:10", "reward_addresses": "aef742cd720083790f58b8dced44b868e2496335061c2c5256b44e45"}
{"number": 96062768, "identifiers": null, "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:50:59", "reward_addresses": "c4a4b16b33b63da2117f4a84d3ea686f34fcf9f4603ce016af9e39aa"}
{"number": 96062810, "identifiers": "SWM03", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:51:41", "reward_addresses": "1ed4fce12691c3f5ea8f2905fc50c7a460a5b832b6d8712de192c656"}
{"number": 96062886, "identifiers": "JUST", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:52:57", "reward_addresses": "6e244c629b648b065ca4854ea7f8fb9838be54f688a5ee005074bdba"}
{"number": 96062892, "identifiers": "WSKS", "timestamp": "2023-06-24 17:53:03", "reward_addresses": "09340f1229f485a7ed7495e0369b5f02f8cc3d58b810c70a42e930b0"}
...
```

With this information, the EDI consensus tool counts the actual number of blocks minted per entity (as opposed to stake distribution) to calculate metrics.  Unfortunately I can't seem to get the raw data I need.  I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

For reference, here's a Python snippet of what I'm trying to do...

get_solana_info.py

```
def get_block_data(start_slot, end_slot):
    url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

    # Get a list of blocks
    payload = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "getBlocks",
        "params": [start_slot, end_slot]
    }

    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    block_numbers = response.json().get('result')

    with open('solana_raw_data.json', 'a') as f:
        for block_number in block_numbers:
            # Get detailed information for each block
            payload = {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "id": 1,
                "method": "getBlock",
                "params": [block_number, {"encoding": "json", "transactionDetails": "full", "rewards": True}]
            }

            response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
            print(block_number)
            block = response.json().get('result')

            if block:
                if 'transactions' in block:
                    del block['transactions']
                json.dump(block, f, indent=4)
                f.write('\n')
...
```

And a snippet of the results that seem to be missing any identifiers or rewards addresses:

solana_raw_data.json

```
{
    "blockHeight": null,
    "blockTime": 1605759788,
    "blockhash": "9dabg4HJCqo5ac8DtyHnbmoy3YJr3C4v2yyM8ec3bSRU",
    "parentSlot": 49999999,
    "previousBlockhash": "BfV97pDB3LHYafqBa2MYR1JHTiro19upkZ6NaAbikray",
    "rewards": []
}
{
    "blockHeight": null,
    "blockTime": 1605759788,
    "blockhash": "9dabg4HJCqo5ac8DtyHnbmoy3YJr3C4v2yyM8ec3bSRU",
    "parentSlot": 49999999,
    "previousBlockhash": "BfV97pDB3LHYafqBa2MYR1JHTiro19upkZ6NaAbikray",
    "rewards": []
}
{
    "blockHeight": null,
    "blockTime": 1605759788,
    "blockhash": "Ci4yhVABcYz5MqSG5N1vyWPHhXm7AtHWH1J7SYHVfDWv",
    "parentSlot": 50000000,
    "previousBlockhash": "9dabg4HJCqo5ac8DtyHnbmoy3YJr3C4v2yyM8ec3bSRU",
    "rewards": []
}
...
```

Any help, direction, or even collaboration with this would be very appreciated.  Also the source is already open source.  This addition of Solana metrics will be added as a pull request:

https://github.com/Blockchain-Technology-Lab/consensus-decentralization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the missing info is the reward address, which in Solana parlance would be the "leader", and the block number, which corresponds to the "block height".

I'm not sure why the block height isn't populated on `getBlock`, because that's definitely the correct thing to do. You can use the slot number as a proxy, but it's not the same thing as block height because blocks can be skipped.

Next, to get the leader, you'll need to correlate the slot of the block with the leader schedule, which you can fetch using `getSlotLeaders` https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getslotleaders

Otherwise, you can use the `blockhash` as an identifier, and the `blockTime` as the timestamp. From there, you should be good to go!

Comment: That plan sounds good, but unfortunately the `getSlotLeaders` endpoint seems to give me the following error no matter what I do:
`{'code': -32602, 'message': 'Invalid slot range: leader schedule for epoch 541 is unavailable'}`

Comment: Ah darn, you're right, it looks like the node only keeps 10 epochs worth of schedules: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/3863bb1bdf0f7c9a0b35c2c19dc50943ca39657e/ledger/src/leader_schedule_cache.rs#L22

In that case, you'll need to use the `getBlock` endpoint with `rewards: true` and see which address received the block rewards. That'll typically be the vote authority of the leader.